# What video game consoles are considered 'retro?'

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic, gaming-consoles

Some answers to this are easy: NES/Famicom, PS1, Game & Watch, etc. However, as time rolls forward, the lines between getting older and retro are becoming more blurred for a lot of video game consoles.

Is there a time period that must pass for a video game system to be considered retro? Is the Gamecube considered retro now? Wii (9 years old)? Xbox? PS2? How do we define retro video game consoles?

Comment: Also very related: [Are retro gaming consoles on-topic?](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/40/621)

Answer (score 7):

The definition of 'retro' comes down to, pure and simple, opinions: for example, I think that PS2 and beyond will never become retro, due to the graphical style.
So only 5th gen and below are considered retro IMO.